# Lower the rate limit for retags

Tags: feature-request, rate-limiting, serial-edits

So we've had a mass retag on [SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). I don't know what the rate limit for retags is, I don't even know whether there is one (though I'd be surprised if there wasn't), but I'm pretty sure it's too high when a user can retag 50 posts in 40 minutes.

I don't know what the limit should be. Quite possibly it shouldn't be a plain limit on the number of retags: I'm far more confident in the quality of 20 retags intermeshed with 10 edits and 15 votes than in the quality of 20 retags straight.

The front page may also be a factor: if the front page is close to being just one user, maybe we should stop this user from editing until others have chimed in.

As usual, moderators should have higher limits, which is not to say none at all.

[image: added new tag ×20]

Comment: I don't think there is one. I've done mass retags before and never had any problems with rate-limiting.

Comment: Some good ideas here.

Comment: I would also suggest a lower limit for users who keep adding the same tag to different questions in few time. I don't know if it is worth adding such checking, but I think that if a user starts adding the same tag to 20 questions in 20 minutes, there is a chance the tag is wrongly added.

Comment: If you have full edit privileges, there is no limit to the *number* of edits, is there?

Comment: @BoPersson 5 per day on your own (old?) posts regardless of privileges. More than that other people's posts, but there's probably a limit.

Comment: [Past record has nothing to do with botness. What would happen if your account was compromised?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129728/178438). So mods shouldn't get this.

Comment: @Manis *"As usual, moderators should have higher limits, **which is not to say none at all**."* (emphasis added) Yes, their account *might* be compromised, but we have to balance that with the desire not to annoy the heck out of them while trying to do their jobs.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Aah, did not see. Thanks..

Comment: How timely.  Someone created about two dozen new tags on SO in the past hour, none of them needed in the least.  I don't know about a *rate limit*, but creation of multiple new tags in a short period of time should certainly be something that sets off flags somewhere...